# How to monkeypatch a static method?

Tags: python, static-methods, monkeypatching

While it's fairly simple to monkeypatch instance methods to classes, e.g.

```
class A(object):
    pass

def a(self):
    print "a"

A.a = a
```

doing this with another class's `@staticmethod` à la

```
class B(object):
    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print "static b"

A.b = B.b
```

results in `A.b()` yielding a

> `TypeError`: unbound method `b()` must be called with `A` instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all, good luck finding the "duplicated" answer when searching for a way to patch a staticmethod.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make A.b a static method and you should be fine:

`A.b = staticmethod(B.b)`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually simple. Though according to the [other question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229691/pointers-to-static-methods-in-python) this is no longer necessary in Python3. Sidenote to self: To figure out whether `B.b` _is_ a static method, compare to `types.FunctionType` (otherwise it's a `types.MethodType`)