# How to monkeypatch one class's instance method to another one?

Tags: python, python-2.x, monkeypatching, instance-methods

Given a class `A` I can simply add an instancemethod `a` via

```
def a(self):
    pass

A.a = a
```

However, if I try to add another class `B`'s instancemethod `b`, i.e. `A.b = B.b`, the attempt at calling `A().b()` yields a

> `TypeError`: unbound method `b()` must be called with `B` instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

(while `B().b()` does fine). Indeed there is a difference between

```
A.a -> <unbound method A.a>
A.b -> <unbound method B.b>  # should be A.b, not B.b
```

So,

- How to fix this?
- Why is it this way? It doesn't seem intuitive, but usually Guido has some good reasons...

Curiously enough, this no longer fails in Python3...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12935356/2225682

Comment: @falsetru which leads to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9663900/321973, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's:

```
class A(object): pass

class B(object):
    def b(self): 
        print 'self class: ' + self.__class__.__name__
```

When you are doing:

```
A.b = B.b
```

You are not attaching a *function* to A, but an *unbound method*. In consequence python only add it as a standard attribute and do not convert it to a A-unbounded method. The solution is simple, attach the underlying function :

```
A.b = B.b.__func__

print A.b
    # print: <unbound method A.b>
a = A()
a.b()
    # print: self class: A
```

I don't know all the difference between unbound methods and functions (only that the first contains the second), neither how all of that work internally. So I cannot explain the reason of it. My understanding is that a method object (bound or not) requires more information and functionalities than a functions, but it needs one to execute.

I would agree that automating this (changing the class of an unbound method) could be a good choice, but I can find reasons not to. It is thus surprising that python 3 differs from python 2. I'd like to find out the reason of this choice.

Comment: Thanks, I feared that would have been more complicated!

Answer (score 2):

When you take the reference to a method on a class instance, the method is bound to that class instance.

`B().b` is equivalent to: `lambda *args, **kwargs: b(<B instance>, *args, **kwargs)`

I suspect you are getting a similarly (but not identically) wrapped reference when evaluating B.b. However, this is not the behavior I would have expected.

Interestingly:

```
A.a = lambda s: B.b(s)
A().a()
```

yields:

> TypeError: unbound method b() must be called with B instance as first
>   argument (got A instance instead)

This suggests that `B.b` is evaluating to a wrapper for the actual method, and the wrapper is checking that 'self' has the expected type. I don't know, but this is probably about interpreter efficiency.

It's an interesting question though. I hope someone can chime in with a more definitive answer.

Comment: Curiously all works fine with Python3, where (see e.g. answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16229691/321973)) this confusing concept of unbound methods has been abandoned

Comment: Huh, as [Juh_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18714082/321973) showed, one simply needs to use `B.b.__func__`. Still a weird "feature", no wonder it's no longer in Python3...